# Multiple conditions in WHILE

Tags: java

I **either** read from  *while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null)*:

```
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(DEST2),charset));
```

**either**   *while (crunchifyIterator.hasNext())*:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<String> crunchifyIterator = list.iterator();
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
if (list !=null) {
    Iterator<String> crunchifyIterator = list.iterator();

    while (crunchifyIterator.hasNext()) {
        //code
    }
}
else 
    while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null)
    {
        //code
    }
```

**only in one while?**

Comment: It might be, but I guarantee you that it would look ten times worse than what you have there.

Comment: You can define a exit condition in a boolean variable, and keep looping **while** it is not true. This way you can evaluate everything inside the while loop

Comment: Why do you want it in one while?

Comment: @ Michael Butscher Because with frond end Comes either File  either  List String(textarea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a boolean set by your type of input and use it in the while

```
while ((isReadingFromFile && (reader1.reader1.readLine() != null)) ||
       crunchifyIterator.hasNext()) {
```

I am not sure it is the best option though maybe better to move the code inside the `while` loops to a private method if you want share code between the 2 loops

```
if (...) {
    while (crunchifyIterator.hasNext()){
        handleLine(crunchifyIterator.next());
    }
} else {
    while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
       handleLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Iterator<String> crunchifyIterator = list.iterator();
while (
   (list!=null && crunchifyIterator.hasNext()) || 
   (list==null && (line = reader1.readLine()) != null)
){
   //code
}
```

But it won't work correctly if the code modifies list. If list changes you should save a copy of list in a variable and use that in the condition instead of list.